# Rails round Active Record query result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Simple question I cannot seem to figure out:

In a controller:

```
@clientsMonthYearQuery = Client.group(:month_year)
```

In a view I have this query

```
@clientsMonthYearQuery.average(:charge)
```

How would I round the query result to round the average to 2 decimal spots?

*note there is a business reason for chaining the AR calc in the view, the example I gave is simplified from the real thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across this while trying to do the same thing with chartkick. I convert the results to an array (an array of arrays actually where each sub-array is [client,charge]) and then round the second value in each sub-array, like so:

```
@clientsMonthYearQuery.average(:charge).to_a
@clientsMonthYearQuery.each do |record|
  record[1] = record[1].round(2)
end
```

I do this in the controller however. You could certainly keep the results as a hash and iterate over it similarly, but I prefer arrays (and chartkick accepts both) and this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can round the number returned by ActiveRecord query like so:

```
@clientsMonthYearQuery.average(:charge).round(2)
```

If you are doing this in a view you can use this handy Rails Helper as well:

```
<%= number_with_precision @clientsMonthYearQuery.average(:charge), :precision => 2 %>
```

Comment: You know I tried that and got: undefined method `round' for #<Hash:0x000000087a5730>

Comment: have you checked if the value returned by  @clientsMonthYearQuery.average(:charge) is of type float or double?

Comment: float.. so I think I have to get the query to round, because this goes into a chartkick gem..

Comment: I think the problem is that the query is a hash, and it's not letting me round the hash

Comment: what is the data type of column :charge?

Comment: the data type of :charge is decimal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select` to do rounding via the database, instead of forcing Ruby to do the rounding (Ruby is slower).

```rb
class Client

  scope :average_charge_by_month_year, -> do
    group(:month_year)
      .select(
        :month_year, 
        'ROUND(AVG(charge)) AS average_charge'
      )
      .order('average_charge DESC')
  end

  class << self

    def average_charge_by_date
      average_quantity_by_product_name.to_a.pluck(
        :month_year,
        :average_charge
      )
    end
    
  end
  
end
```

Then just call:

```rb
Client.average_charge_by_date
```

You'll receive an array, of month_years and rounded average charge.
*(if you want a hash, don't use `.to_a.pluck`, just use `map` and `to_h` instead.)*

Plus, this query orders by the rounded average, another time saver.